# How to use Task.Run(Action<T>)

Tags: c#, .net, delegates, compiler-errors, task-parallel-library

I am attempting to create a method that accepts TcpClient connections and performs a task once a client is connected, "ConnectedAction". I am receiving a compile error when trying to have a new task created to run the delegate "ConnectedAction".

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'void' to 'System.Func'

I believe that this error is because the method is trying to run the "ConnectedAction" method and return void to the Task.Run parameter.

How do I have the Task run the "ConnectedAction" delegate?

```
class Listener
{
    public IPEndPoint ListenerEndPoint {get; private set;}
    public int TotalAttemptedConnections { get; private set; }
    public Action<TcpClient> ConnectedAction { get; private set; }

    public Listener(IPEndPoint listenerEndPoint, Action<TcpClient> connectedAction)
    {
        ConnectedAction = connectedAction;
        ListenerEndPoint = listenerEndPoint;

        Task.Factory.StartNew(Listen, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
    }

    private void Listen()
    {
        TcpListener tcpListener = new TcpListener(ListenerEndPoint);
        tcpListener.Start();

        while (true)
        {
            TcpClient tcpClient = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
            TotalAttemptedConnections++;

            //Error here 
            Task.Run(ConnectedAction(tcpClient));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You should write:

```
Task.Run(() => ConnectedAction(tcpClient));
```

This creates a lambda function that takes no parameters and will call your specified function with the correct argument. The lambda is implicitly wrapped into the delegate type needed by the `Task.Run` parameters.

What you wrote calls the function and then attempts to turn the return value of the function into a delegate.